# How do I log back into my HR database for Oracle SQL Developer( the password expired )?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm having some trouble with logging into the HR database that comes with SQL Developer :

first I log into SQL*Plus like so:

```
sqlplus sys/sys_password as sysdba
```

How do I connect to the HR database after that ? I tried

```
open HR
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: `sqlplus hr/hr_password`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  - my password expired though

Comment: Then reset it - you apparently have a SYSDBA account to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could reset its password:

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

And then just use this password to log in.

Comment: This gives me a `ORA-01109 : database not open` error

Comment: @Coffee then the problem isn't that HR's password expired, it's that the database has not fully started up. You can open it with `alter database open`.

Comment: I need to find a solid DB book and eat it :P

Comment: The oracle 2day dba guide is what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897.pdf